# Select all rows from table A join table B on account number, but exclude rows where tableB.foo == bar. Can I get this data set in one query?

Tags: sql, database

Table A contains basic customer information including account number.  Each valid account number appears in exactly one row in table A.

Table B contains information about which flags are set for which customers. 
 Columns in Table B are account number, flag key, flag value.  Most account numbers appear in multiple rows in Table B, one for each flag that is set on that account.  However some account numbers do not have any flags set and do not appear at all in table B.  Flags do not have default settings and can be undefined.  If there is no row in table B for a particular account number and flag key combination, that flag is undefined on that account.

The only flag we care about for this question is flag key Foo.  There are many customers who have Foo set to something and many who do not have it set at all.

Goal: Select all the customer info from table A for all customers that do *not* have flag Foo set at all.

My current solution that works is doing 2 queries and then processing the results.  One query selects all rows from table A.  The other query selects all rows from table A join table B on account number where tableB.FlagKey=Foo.

Then some code I wrote just iterates through the results of the table B query and generates a list of account numbers.  Then it iterates through the results of the table A query and just keeps rows with account numbers that don't appear in the list of account numbers I built.

This works fine but I feel like this "should" be possible to do in one DB query, but I can't figure out how to write that query.  I'm not very experienced in writing DB queries.

Comment: Are you familiar with `EXISTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B
    ON A.ACC_NO = B.ACC_NO
WHERE B.FOO <> 'bar'
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me understand.

I had to change it a bit.  I used left outer join, because some customers appear only in table A, never in B. I want to select them too.  

I also changed it to select distinct account numbers.  Because some account numbers appear in many different rows in table B.
I now have something close to 
`SELECT DISTINCT act_num FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON act_num WHERE B.FlagKey <> 'Foo'`

But I am doing it on a proprietary system, slightly different syntax and it returns all columns from A.  As long as the row has a distinct act_num.

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.flagkey = 'foo');
```

This assumes that "not set at all" means that the key is not in the second table.